# Replace gnome-terminal with konsole in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator, konsole

I installed **konsole** and uninstalled **gnome-terminal** by doing:

```bsh
sudo apt install -y konsole
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gnome-terminal
```

And then tried:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

To set **konsole** as the default emulator, wich returns:

```
There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/konsole
Nothing to configure.
```

But neither the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> shortcut works nor do right click open terminal.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the command:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

And selecting Konsole from the terminals menu. I still had to go to Linux Mint's "Preferred Applications" menu and set Konsole as the default emulator. That was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

What is your output when you now run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`?

Mine is:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/konsole                  40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/konsole                  40        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: I updated my question